# Calling a method from another class, variables not passed on

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, core-bluetooth, instances

I ma trying to send Hex data from IOS to bluetooth peripheral. I have a 3rd party keyboard that I customised so that one button called SEND dissmisses the keyboard and sends the information from the textfield to a designated characteristic called control.

I have two classes:

*MRHexKeyboard* and *BTLECentralViewController*

The sending function works fine if I use a button placed on the BTLECentralViewController, but when I call the send function from the keyboard this no longer works as there is no characteristic to write to.

In BTLECentralViewController:

```
-(IBAction)sendCmdControl:(id)sender;{
    //When button is pressed send data
    [self sendDataCMD];

}

-(void)sendDataCMD{
    if (!_control) {
        NSLog(@"No Characteristic to write to");
        return;
    }
    //sending commandToSend to characteristic 'control'
    [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:commandToSend forCharacteristic:self.control type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

Now when I call this form the keyboard method I do this

MRHexKeyboard:

```
 BTLECentralViewController* myScript = [[BTLECentralViewController alloc] init]; 
 [myScript sendDataCMD];
```

The problem I am having is : method runs but there is no characteristic to send data to so the variables haven't been passed on.

I believe its because the class MRHexKeyboard doesn't see the clause declared in BTLECentralViewController??

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager      *centralManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral          *discoveredPeripheral;
```

How would I make them accessible to other classes??

I am very fresh to iOS and ObjectiveC.

Comment: `BTLECentralViewController* myScript = [[BTLECentralViewController alloc] init]`. You are creating a whole new object.

Comment: Expanding on Larme's comment a bit: Properties are on the object instance, not the class. Creation (alloc & init) of a new view controller gets a nil centralManager and discoveredPeripheral property unless you do something to provision those properties. I'm unclear on what you expect. This is pretty fundamental OO stuff.

Comment: @CuriousRabit -> thanks I think I am seriously lacking OO basics -> do you know where I could find some good reference material on this...?

Comment: @CuriousRabbit In my language I am expecting to set the missing variable as global so the when I call this function from a different file it can see them. i.e. provision for centralManager and discoveredPeripheral to be visible when I call sendDataCMD

Comment: @ErykSokolowski - One source is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

As by seeing your code, i can suggest to create a singleton object of CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral, so it won't be nil when you initialise the ViewController.  Or you can create a BLEManager singleton class to perform all the activities.